# Search text file in MATLAB for a string to begin process

Tags: string, matlab, search

I have a fairly large text file and am trying to search for a particular term so that i can start a process after that point, but this doesn't seem to be working for me:

```
fileID = fopen(resfile,'r');


line  = 0;
    while 1
    tline = fgetl(fileID);
    line = line + 1;
    if ischar(tline)
        startRow = strfind(tline, 'OptimetricsResult');
        if isfinite(startRow) == 1;
            break
        end
    end
end
```

The answer I get is 9, but my text file:

```
$begin '$base_index$'
$begin 'properties'
all_levels=000000000000
time(year=000000002013, month=000000000006, day=000000000020, hour=000000000008, min=000000000033, sec=000000000033)
version=000000000000
$end 'properties'
$begin '$base_index$'
$index$(pos=000000492036, lin=000000009689, lvl=000000000000)
$end '$base_index$'
```

definitely doesn't have that in the first 9 rows?

If I ctrl+F the file, I know that OptimetricsResult only appears once, and that it's 6792 lines down

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think your script somehow works, and you were just looking at the wrong variable. I assume that the answer you get is `startRow = 9` and not `line = 9`. Check the variable `line`. By the way, note that you're not checking an End-of-File, so your `while` loop might run indefinitely the file doesn't contain your search string.

An alternative approach, (which is much simpler in my humble opinion) would be reading all lines at once (each one stored as a separate string) with `textscan`, and then applying `regexp` or `strfind`:

```
%// Read lines from input file
fid = fopen(filename, 'r');
C = textscan(fid, '%s', 'Delimiter', '\n');
fclose(fid);

%// Search a specific string and find all rows containing matches
C = strfind(C{1}, 'OptimetricsResult');
rows = find(~cellfun('isempty', C));
```

Comment: +1, although usually I'm a bit weary when reading whole textfiles into memory (what if a 279 TB textfile comes along?)

Comment: @RodyOldenhuis I hear you :) but I wouldn't be parsing 279 TB in MATLAB in the first place though (I _did_ actually try something like that not long ago)

Answer (score 2):

I can't reproduce your problem.

Are you sure you've properly closed the file before re-running this script? If not, the internal line counter in `fgetl` does not get reset, so you get false results. Just issue a `fclose all` on the MATLAB command prompt, and add a `fclose(fileID);` after the loop, and test again.

In any case, I suggest modifying your infinite-loop (with all sorts of pitfalls) to the following finite loop:

```
haystack = fopen(resfile,'r');
needle   = 'OptimetricsResult';

line  = 0;
found = false;
while ~feof(haystack)

    tline = fgetl(haystack);
    line = line + 1;

    if ischar(tline) && ~isempty(strfind(tline, needle))
        found = true;
        break;
    end

end

if ~found
    line = NaN; end

fclose(fileID);


line
```

You could of course also leave the searching to more specialized tools, which come free with most operating systems:

```
haystack = 'resfile.txt';
needle   = 'OptimetricsResult';

if ispc % Windows
    [~,lines] = system(['find /n "' needle '" ' haystack]);
elseif isunix % Mac, Linux
    [~,lines] = system(['grep -n "' needle '" ' haystack]);
else 
    error('Unknown operating system!');
end
```

You'd have to do a bit more parsing to extract the line number from `C`, but I trust this will be no issue.

Comment: If I could another +1 for variable names I would :)